# Stripe Connect: Charging an existing customer against a "connected" (Standalone) account

Tags: ruby, stripe-payments, stripe-connect

If attempting to charge a customer record (which has an associated credit-card) *via* a [connected account](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/), I get an error claiming, "No such customer: cus_xxxx" -- even though making a charge to the same-exact customer will work fine when *not* using a "connected" account (when charging via the platform account).

For example, consider the following Ruby code, assuming we have a "connected" (Standalone) account with ID `acct_ABC123`:

```ruby
# Use the (secret) API key for the "platform" or base account.
Stripe.api_key = 'sk_[...]'

customer = Stripe::Customer.create(email: 'customer@example.com')

# Associate a credit-card with the customer.
token = # Generate a token (e.g., using Stripe Checkout).
customer.sources.create(source: token)

# Attempt to charge the card via the connected account...
Stripe::Charge.create({ amount: 150, currency: 'usd', customer: customer.id,
                        application_fee: 25 }, stripe_account: 'acct_ABC123')
```

The last line there leads to a `Stripe::InvalidRequestError` exception, with the "No such customer" error mentioned above. However, the same charge will go through fine if we just try to run it on the "platform" account (without the `stripe_account` parameter and no `application_fee`)...

```ruby
Stripe::Charge.create({ amount: 150, currency: 'usd', customer: customer.id }
```

Answer (score 7):

For some (confusing and slightly bizarre) reason, you must add the intermediate step of [creating a new token](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/shared-customers#making-tokens) when making charges against "Shared Customers" (customers that will be charged through one or more connected accounts). So, assuming we've already created the `customer` with an associated credit-card (as per the question), the working code ends up looking something like this...

```
token = Stripe::Token.create({ customer: customer.id },
                             { stripe_account: 'acct_ABC123' })
Stripe::Charge.create({ amount: 150, currency: 'usd', source: token.id,
                        application_fee: 25 }, stripe_account: 'acct_ABC123')
```

As an aside, I would consider Stripe's error message ("No such customer") to be a bug and the fact that this extra step (generating a token) is required only for "Stripe Connect" charges a confusing quirk.

Comment: N.B.: If you're still getting the "no such customer" error even after creating a new token, double-check that you aren't still passing in a `customer` parameter when creating the charge.